# Kogito Debugging DMN Test Scenarios

Tags: drools, kie, dmn, kogito

Using Kogito I'm trying to create a test scenario for a DMN file that returns an array. I created a simple DMN that would return an array of objects regardless of the input for the sake of testing.

But tests are failing if I add a value to the return array, they pass if I have zero elements as the expected result which makes no sense. Looks like DMN returns no values if executed from the test.

If I run this on the api it always returns an element on the array as expected.

I have been trying to figure out how to debug this on visual studio with no luck

Expected result is being written like this on the file, but again appear no result is coming back

```
[{"name":"\"jose\"", "ages":"[12,13]"}]
```

[simple.dmn](https://pastebin.com/M8qkYVVy)

[simpleTest.scesim](https://pastebin.com/EY2FQ0YW)

Basically some method to debug this would be great or any help that can point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

Jose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two points to tackle here, one is related to the error you faced, and the second is to understand how to debug a `scesim` asset during its running phase.

- Your case failure: Unfortunately, `scesim` assets have a well-known limitation in the case of nested Collection in type, which is your case. In particular, you defined the following list for your `Simple` type in the expected column:

[image]

The problem here is with `ages` fields, which is a nested List. Providing `[12,13]` as a parameter of that list, is formally correct. But, due to the limitation I mentioned, it currently it doesn't work. There's a workaround you can use, which is to Define a List using an expression, as shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

The expression `?  = {"name":"jose","ages":[12, 13]}` means to check for the equality of the actual value (`?`) with an object which contains a field `name` with value `jose` and a field `ages` with `[12, 13]` as the value. Please note, according to your defined logic, you expect a `Simple` type list with one item only. If you `Simple` type returns a list with multiple items, the expression should be composed by a List rather than a single object (Eg. `?  = [{"name":"jose","ages":[12, 13]}, {"name":"john","ages":[1, 3]}, .. ]`
We are aware this is not ideal, we are defining a way to improve this use-case experience. Stay tuned with KIE channels to know more or to give hints to improve this!

- How to debug a Test Scenario assets: In this example I'm using IntelliJ as IDE, but it works on VSCode too. Referring to your `scesim` file, let's run it with `mvn clean install`. As you reported it will fail, with an exception. Let's try to put a breakpoint in one of the reported line in the stacktrace (Eg. at `org.drools.scenariosimulation.backend.runner.AbstractScenarioRunner.singleRunScenario(AbstractScenarioRunner.java:125`)

[image]

Put a breakpoint on that line. Now, to launch the `scesim` engine in debug mode, go to your `scesim` activator class (typically named  `KogitoScenarioJunitActivatorTest`). Here, you can Run/Debug your `scesim` assets like a Junit test class.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Yeser, I think for this particular one it might make more sense to do a custom java test. Would you have an example of this?

Comment: Hi Jose. Of course, you can refer to this example [DMN Quarkus Example](https://github.com/kiegroup/kogito-examples/tree/stable/kogito-quarkus-examples/dmn-quarkus-example), which contains both test scenario and [java junit](https://github.com/kiegroup/kogito-examples/blob/stable/kogito-quarkus-examples/dmn-quarkus-example/src/test/java/org/kie/kogito/dmn/quarkus/example/TrafficViolationTest.java) test for a DMN asset

Comment: @josesuero Hi, if my answer satisfies your need, can you please accept it? Thank you :)